# Why am I not able to read JSON data in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, json

I have jQuery data. But am not able to read it. I am not sure why.

Here is the link

```
$(document).ready(function(e){
      $('#tolaststep').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
         var errormessages=[{
                                username: 
                               {
                                    required: "Username is Required"
                                }
                            }];
    alert("Here I am getting the result   "+errormessages[0].username.required);
$('input').each(function()
           {
              if ($(this).val() === "") 
              {
                    var currentid=$(this).attr("id");
                    alert(typeof currentid);
                    alert("I am not getting result here :( "+errormessages[0].currentid.required);
                       $(this).css("border", "1px solid red");
                }

           });
       });
    });
```

http://jsfiddle.net/btJDH/

Comment: It would be helpful if you property format the code.

Comment: @EricJ. I did it...please see it now

Comment: It fails because errormessages[0].currentid is undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Accessing properties of an object with the key stored in a variable requires square brackets:

```
errormessages[0][currentid].required
```

Otherwise, the JS interpreter thinks that you're looking for a key "currentid".

Comment: no its not working..please edit and check it out in jsfiddle.

Comment: I did with the dot...sorry ...Thanks a lot